# How to compare imaginary coherence values?

Tags: python, eeg, coherence, array-signal-processing

High, I am currently writing my Master's thesis on susceptibility for hypnosis. I am comparing EGG signals of lowly and highly susceptible individuals.

The imaginary coherence is given by:

$$ \text{ImCoh} = \frac{\mathcal{Im}\{E\{S_{xy}\}\}}{ \sqrt{ E\{S_{xx}\} E\{S_{yy}\}} }$$

I found out that I can calculate the coherence like the `scipy.signal.coherence` function with the following code:

````
sfarrA, Pxx = scipy.signal.welch(ex_sig1[0], fs=128)
sfarrB, Pyy = scipy.signal.welch(ex_sig1[9], fs=128)
sfarrAB, Pxy = scipy.signal.csd(ex_sig1[0],ex_sig1[9],fs=128) ```

coherence = abs(Pxy)**2/(Pxx*Pyy)
````

Next I calculate the imaginary coherence using following code:

```
Icoh = np.imag(Pxy)/np.sqrt(Pxx*Pyy)
```

As a result I get an array of negative and non-negative values.

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.15618352,  0.09958203,  0.00483643,  0.02767622,
        0.07590722,  0.06308123,  0.05571067,  0.0312004 , -0.06364436,
       -0.15178242, -0.0313257 ,  0.01023862, -0.02718701, -0.03659143,
        0.04386298, -0.05511231, -0.05728281, -0.03789811, -0.07106073,
       -0.34574961, -0.27614587, -0.27608529, -0.37483751, -0.34951999,
```

How could I compare these values in a meaningful way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Your signals are real-valued vectors? Can you make your data available?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes they are real valued. Imaginary coherence is defined in a way, that it can have negative or positive values. I cannot make the data available.